# Boost.Interprocess - created managed_shared_memory could not be found

Tags: c++, boost, xulrunner, boost-interprocess

I'm about to use shared memory for interprocess communication (obviously ;) between a xulrunner extension (component) and a plugin (NPAPI). Both are written in C++!

I was following the instructions of the [boost lib document](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_interprocess_map)

Now: The creation of the shared memory is working fine by doing this:

```
struct shm_remove
   {
       shm_remove() { NS_BI::shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
      ~shm_remove() { NS_BI::shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
   } remover;


   _myShMemSegment = NS_BI::managed_shared_memory( NS_BI::open_or_create, "MySharedMemory", 65536 ) ;
   SHMEM_ALLOCATOR alloc_inst( _myShMemSegment.get_segment_manager() ) ;

   _pMyShMemMap = _myShMemSegment.construct<SHMEM_MAP>("cgfMap")
                                                        (std::less<int>()
                                                        , alloc_inst) ;
```

The path

```
C:\Users\All Users\boost_interprocess\<aNumber>\
```

shows me a cryptic named file, during the process is running. By closing the program, this file gets deleted. So far so good.

I try to open this shared memory in another process with:

```
NS_BI::managed_shared_memory( NS_BI::open_read_only, "MySharedMemory") ;
```

but then it throws the boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception *System cannot find the file specified*

If I do

```
NS_BI::managed_shared_memory( NS_BI::open_or_create, "MySharedMemory", 1024) ;
```

I get a second file in the Users path in the exact same subdirectory. 
So why couldn't the first one be found by the consumer process?

Btw: If I'm trying to open the file in the path with  a texteditor (notepad++, etc), it couldn't because it asserts that the file doesn't exist.

Thanks for your time!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
struct shm_remove
{
    shm_remove() { NS_BI::shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
   ~shm_remove() { NS_BI::shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
} remover;
```

is the original code from the boost documentation. In case of the example that worked great. But in my case (to be honest I'm not sure WHY) I have to call

```
NS_BI::shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory");
```

right before to build up the shared memory.

You should not forget to do the same in your destructor to delete it!